# Magnetic Declination

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an android app to show the magnetic declination ,but I don't no how to find magnetic declination at our current location ,if anyone know please help me thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GeomagneticField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html) class.

> Estimates magnetic field at a given point on Earth, and in particular, to compute the magnetic declination from true north.